# How can I run multiple unix commands sequentially using a single shortcut command?

Tags: command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, alias

I usually go through files using the following commands:

```
cd first
pwd
ls
cd second
ls
```

This a more generic way of my work. Can I execute all the commands one by one by itself by calling "some secret command"? . The point here is to reduce the typing, since I literally type all of the above lines at least 25 times a day.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're looking for. You can `cd` into nested directories: `cd first/second`. To input multiple commands in a single prompt, use a semicolon: `cd first; pwd` Or are you looking for an alias/bash function, which triggers `ls` automatically after changing directories?

Comment: Yes I am looking to stack all of the above commands to some file or whatever means and use a simpler version of command that makes me type lesser whenever I want to run a series of commands.

Comment: (and is bash even your shell?)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: I just realised that `first`, `second` are just placeholders for your real dirnames, right? 
In that case, instead of an alias you can create a function in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
function pipe(){
    first=$1
    second=$2

    cd -- "$first"; pwd; ls; cd -- "$second"; ls
}
```

Source your `~/.bashrc` and then you can call pipe with 2 input arguments (the names of your `first` and `second` dirs:

```
pipe first_dir_name second_dir_name
```

=====

You can create an alias for this series of commands.

Add to your `~/.bashrc` the following line:

```
# 'pipe' is the name of your alias, you can choose any name you want

alias pipe="cd first; pwd; ls; cd second; ls"
```

Source your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

You can now start executing `pipe` in your terminal that will be executing your series of commands. Of course, you have to ensure that you call `pipe` from the correct dir that allows you to `cd` to the `first` and `second` dirs.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by Source your ~/.bashrc. Do I have to store the function in a file and then call it? Or do you pose some other solution. I am a novice here and I would like a step by step approach. And I will use the original directory and not just placeholders. Whole point is to run series of commands one by one using least typing work everytime

Comment: `.bashrc` is a file in your home directory, the full path is `~/.bashrc`. Open it and add the lines I've written above: `function pipe(){ ... }`. Save and close your `.bashrc` and then type in your teminal: `source ~/.bashrc`. You're then set to start using `pipe dir1 dir2` in your terminal..

Comment: I will definitely try it. Thanks for the contribution.

Comment: You can upvote and/or accept my answer if you find it useful. Thanks